# Finding Pathline Equation of a Fluid Particle in an Unsteady Flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

> Given the 2-D unsteady Eulerian fluid velocity field
>   $$\underline{u}(\underline{r}, t) = a\Big[-y\underline{\hat{\imath}} + (x - bt)\underline{\hat{\jmath}}\Big]\quad\text{with}\quad\underline{r}_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$$
>   find
>
> (i) the equation of the pathline for the fluid particle at $\underline{r}_0$ at $t = 0$
>
> (ii)the equation of the streamline at time $t$ which passes through $\underline{r}_0$

So I see that
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -ay,\,\frac{dy}{dt} = ax - abt,\,\frac{dz}{dt} = 0\quad\text{with}\quad x=x_0,\, y=y_0,\, z=z_0\,\,\text{at}\,\, t=0$$
So then I start to solve
$$z=z_0,\,\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -a\frac{dy}{dt} = -a^2x + a^2bt$$
Then (after lots of working) this leads to a sol. of 
$$x = x_0\cos(at) + B\sin(at) + bt,\,\, y = \Big(y_0 + \frac{b}{a}\Big)\cos(at) + D\sin(at) - \frac{b}{a}$$
Now, my problem is that I don't know what to do next to find the Pathline? How do I find these two unknown constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is different than yours. The pathlines are curves $(x(t), y(t), z(t))$ satisfying the system of ODEs
\begin{alignat*}{3}
x'(t) & = -ay(t), && \qquad x(0) && = x_0 \tag{1}\\
y'(t) & = a(x(t) - bt), && \qquad y(0) && = y_0 \tag{2}\\
z'(t) & = 0, && \qquad z(0) && = z_0. \tag{3} 
\end{alignat*}
Equation $(3)$ implies that $z(t) = z_0$. Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $t$ and substituting $(2)$ we find that
$$ x''(t) = -ay'(t) = -a^2(x(t) - bt) $$
and rearranging yields
$$ x''(t) + a^2x(t) = a^2bt. $$
It can be shown that the general solution is 
$$ x(t) = A\cos(at) + B\sin(at) + bt. $$
The initial condition $x(0) = x_0$ gives $A = x_0$, and the initial condition $x'(0) = -ay(0) = -ay_0$ (This is essentially $(1)$ at time $t=0$) gives
$$ -ay_0 = aB + b \implies B = \frac{-ay_0 - b}{a} = -y_0 - \frac{b}{a}. $$
Consequently, 
$$ x(t) = x_0\cos(at) - \left(y_0 + \frac{b}{a}\right)\sin(at) + bt $$
and the equation of the pathline for any time $t\ge 0$ is
$$ \begin{cases}
\, x(t) & = x_0\cos(at) - \left(y_0 + \frac{b}{a}\right)\sin(at) + bt \\
\, y(t) & = -\frac{1}{a}\Big[-ax_0\sin(at) - \left(ay_0 + b\right)\cos(at) + b\Big] \\
\, z(t) & = z_0.
\end{cases} $$

Comment: yes at the part where you have found $x_0$ you set $t = 0$ so would that not then make $x_0 = A + b\cdot 0 = A$? And what you have done for line 5 I didn't know I could just sub in $y_0$. So I'm just wondering if the sol. for $x$ is $$x(t) = x_0\cos(at) - y_0\sin(at) + bt$$ @Chee

Comment: So then if I differentiate $x$ wrt $t$ I get $$x^{\prime}(t) = -ax_0\sin(at) - ay_0\cos(at) + b\quad\Rightarrow\quad y = x_0\sin(at) + y_0\cos(at) - \frac{b}{a}$$ @Chee

Comment: @Michael You are absolutely right on $A=x_0$, so $B\neq -y_0$ in this case. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Michael which is line 5 for you?

Comment: for line 5 I was talking about where you said $$x^{\prime}(0) = -ay(0) = -ay_0$$ I didn't know that I could do that.

So then for the streamline equation would that just be at $s=0$
$$
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\frac{dx}{ds} & = -ay, && \qquad x(0) && = x_0 \tag{1}\\
\frac{dy}{ds} & = a(x - bt), && \qquad y(0) && = y_0 \tag{2}\\
\frac{dz}{ds} & = 0, && \qquad z(0) && = z_0. \tag{3} 
\end{alignat*}
$$
Which is leading to the same answer for $x$ so would it be the same? There doesn't appear to be a change in the working @Chee

Comment: @Michael Well we are going circular in some sense because we obtained the ODE in terms of $x(t)$ only by differentiating (1) and using (2), really all we have is that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are related through equation (1) and (2) and that's exactly what we need to exploit. For the streamline, you have the correct answer, the only difference now is that the independent variables in your system of ODEs is the streamline parameterisation variable $s$ instead of $t$.

Comment: @Michael You cannot just integrate your first two ODEs with respect to $s$, because your RHS which involve $x,y$, depends on both $s$ and $t$, i.e. $x = x(s;t), y = y(s;t)$.

Comment: Yeah I did feel like it was an incorrect approach. But yes, my first line of thinking was to follow the same approach as before which would lead to the same answer with just being in terms of $s$ rather than $t$ @CheeHan